# What siddhis are achieved when one attains turiya?

Tags: yoga, siddhi

Can someone list siddhis one achieves when one attains turiya? Are all Ashta siddhis achieved when one attains turiya or does it only exist at six Chakras below sahasrara, is siddhis like spaceshifting or teleportation like narada or creating copies of oneself to be at faraway places, like yogi described in autobiography of a yogi, possible in turiya?

Comment: when one attains Bhairava nature, he gets Ashta Siddhis because Bhairava is Ashta Siddhi nayagan. There's nothing more left in Turiya because to realize brahman, you need to beyond siddhis. And basically if you ask for power, I will say in Turiya, whatever you think will manifest. Whatever you speak will turn to reality. You will be a source of light to this whole world! And your body itself will become a "JYOTI" here

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but what is bhairava nature, and when or how is it achieved? by bhairava sadhana? Is there Any tantras/sutras for it?

Comment: I think Siddhis can be attained even before reaching Turiya. And when one attains Turiya s/he would not be interested in Siddhis.

Comment: You know Bhairava - avatar of Shiva? Bhairava is a stage where you become Niravana. Where Manas and Buddhi is in Nirvana stage. There's no Bhairava sadhana. Bhairava means where your Manas is in Niravana... Dont compare this Nirvana with Buddha.

Comment: @Pandya Correct! After reaching Turya state, There will not be any desire left.

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 Bhairava is highest stage of realization as per Kashmiri Shaivism, Once one reaches to this stage there won't be anything left to attain thereafter.

Comment: Yes I do Know that bhairava is manifestation, form of Lord shiva. Though I didn't knew that, thanks for the information.

Comment: Can you let me know if you get one of the siddhis?

Comment: Hello you are reaching turiya daily but you are not aware did acquire any siddhi no right.. you have to be aware when you go to sleep next time that you are reaching turiya for sure

Comment: Yes, I do know that. Samudra manthana starts at night, resulting in production of Amrita, as well as it filling nadis, resulting in turiya, lucid dreams, but then instead of this universe, our soul enters multiverses, parallel universes.

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 as far as I know only Brahma siddhi or Naishkarmya siddhi is guranteed, no other siddhi is guaranteed. You can get enlightened and have no Siddhi at all. Or you can various kinds of siddhi and be horribly ignorant. Patanjali Yoga sutras are of opinion that siddhis are like the flowers you find on the path, beautiful but you should not get stuck to them.

Comment: Siddhis purpose is to make you aware of non physical dimension which is not visible to senses!!!! Thats it!!!

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto "Do you think one who will get Siddhi will come in public and proclaim that ?" Yes! Maybe I am ignorant but I hope someone will do so someday.  "It will never happen." I hope it will happen someday but probably you are right and we should therefore dismiss the existence of siddhi's.

Comment: "Let's say someone claim over internet that he got Siddhi, now how will you verify it" I don't know yet but I will figure it out. "So it's better to experience it ourselves to find that out." If I tell that if you give  me all of your money you will attain moksha immediately would you experience it for yourself? @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto "Do you really think Moksha can be attained by giving all your money ?"  I think you didn't understand what I said. Let's say someone claims over the internet that someone got Moksha via this way, now how will you verify it ? There is no way, right! So it's better to experience it ourselves to find that out.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto who says anything about a joke?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Yoga Sutras of Patanjali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali), various Siddhis can be achieved by making Samyama  (संयम​) on subtle things or quantities. First of all let's clear what is called Samyama:

(Quoting from *Swami Vivekanada's Rajayoga: [Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms : Chapter III - Powers](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/powers.htm)*)

The combination of Dharana, Dhyana and Samadhi is called Samyama:

> त्रयमेकत्र संयमः ॥४॥
>
> 4. (These) three (when practiced) in regard to one object is Samyama.
>
> When a man can direct his mind to any particular object and fix it there, and then keep it there for a long time, separating the object from the internal part, this is **Samyama**; or Dharana, Dhyana, and Samadhi, one following the other, and making one. The form of the thing has vanished, and only its meaning remains in the mind.
>
> तज्जयात् प्रज्ञाऽऽलोकः ॥५॥
>
> 5. By the conquest of that comes light of knowledge.
>
> **When one has succeeded in making this Samyama, all powers come under his control. This is the great instrument of the Yogi.** The objects of knowledge are infinite, and they are divided into the gross, grosser, grossest and the fine, finer, finest and so on. This Samyama should be first applied to gross things, and when you begin to get knowledge of this gross, slowly, by stages, it should be brought to finer things.

Read Sutras from 16<sup>th</sup> onwards which mentions various Siddhis (Listing of Siddhis as follows):

- knowledge of past and future
- knowledge of all animal sounds
- knowledge of past life
- knowledge of others' mind
- power of disappearing the body
- receiving strength of animals
- knowledge of the fine, the obstructed, and the remote things
- knowledge of cluster of stars, of motions of stars
- ceasing hunger without eating food!
- fixity of body, indestructible body
- entering to another's body
- waking on thorns, stand in fire, die at will
- divine hearing, go through skies
- mastery of elements
- by the power of Prâtibha, all knowledge is gained.
- omnipotence and omniscience

But these siddhis are actually obstacles for yogi to attainment of highest goal which is Kaivalya Mukti.

> ते समाधावुपसर्गा व्युत्थाने सिद्धयः ॥३८॥
>
> 38. These are obstacles to Samadhi <sup>**§**</sup> ; but they are powers in the worldly state.
>
> To the Yogi knowledge of the enjoyments of the world comes by the junction of the Purusha and the mind. If he wants to make Samyama on the knowledge that they are two different things, nature and soul, he gets knowledge of the Purusha. From that arises discrimination. When he has got that discrimination, he gets the Pratibha, the light of supreme genius. **These powers, however, are obstructions to the attainment of the highest goal, the knowledge of the pure Self, and freedom.** These are, as it were, to be met in the way; and if the Yogi rejects them, he attains the highest. If he is tempted to acquire these, his further progress is barred.
>
> तद्वैराग्यादपि दोषबीजक्षये कैवल्यम् ॥५१॥
>
> 51. By giving up even these powers comes the destruction of the very seed of evil, which leads to Kaivalya.
>
> He attains aloneness, independence, and becomes free. When one gives up even the ideas of omnipotence and omniscience, there comes entire rejection of enjoyment, of the temptations from celestial beings. When the Yogi has seen all these wonderful powers, and rejected them, he reaches the goal. What are all these powers? Simply manifestations. *They are no better than dreams. Even omnipotence is a dream.* It depends on the mind. So long as there is a mind it can be understood, but the goal is beyond even the mind.

So, as explained in the Sutra-38, when a yogi rejects all the siddhis and has no desires, s/he reaches to the highest goal which is to know the pure/true self beyond mind and intellect. Here knowing this pure/true self is identical to attaining Turiya as per [*the definition of Turiya*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10761/277) from [Mandukya Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-atharva-veda/mandukya-upanishad/):

> 7. **The Fourth** is thought of as that which is not conscious of the internal world, nor conscious of the external world, nor conscious of both the worlds, nor dense with consciousness, nor simple consciousness, nor unconsciousness, which is unseen, actionless, incomprehensible, un-inferable, unthinkable, indescribable, whose proof consists in the identity of the Self (in all states), in which all phenomena come to a cessation, and which is unchanging, auspicious, and non-dual. **That is the Self; that is to be known.**

---

<sup>§ For more information about Samadhi: Visit [Types and stages of Samadhi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31761/277).</sup>

Comment: Good answer. You can supplement stating the cases of saints, who obtained liberation but without powers.@Pandya

Comment: If a person has attained turiya, would samyama on specific things, still give siddhi or do they only exist in between lower 6 Chakras.?

Comment: Since in turiya, we're no different than purusha, body is fully pure of all toxin, heat, there's nothing to breathe, what happens if we manually breath in external air? Creation of five elements, and their sub Manifestations etc microcosmically, like macroscopically purusha creating the universe/purushamedha yajna?

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 After attaining Turiya, no need to do Samyama, s/he can do all those things a Yogi can do by Samyama.