# Ability to give 'Shraap' (curse) is a type of Siddhi or what?

Tags: curse, siddhi, yogi

The answer to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35114/what-siddhis-are-achieved-when-one-attains-turiya) question describes the various siddhis that are achieved when one attains turiya but my question is whether the ability to give shraap (curse, श्राप) is also a type of Siddhi attained or is it something totally different altogether?

Comment: what is shraap ? I thought it was shaap (curse)

Comment: @ram Both are correct and acceptable. शाप and श्राप.

Comment: @Aman Shraap is not Sanskrit. It's a distortion of Shaap

Comment: @Aman, i just checked sanskrit dictionary, it is [shaap](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=shaap&direct=au) only, not shraap

Comment: I think it's possible to curse, as well as since turiya is none other than brahman, that's why Brahmins are called so, since we're brahman, equal to God, doing any harm/malice to turiya, incurs bad Karma. As well as killing a turiya, results in brahmanahatya dosha.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Indeed. श्राप is in Hindi I guess.

Comment: @ram  शाप and श्राप. Both are correct and acceptable ***in HIndi***.