# Can gods appear to a turiya person

Tags: gods, mantras

Can gods appear to a turiya person, by doing tapas or mantra with pure devotion combined with bodily spiritually purity, , as well as is it possible to ask for and get boons or astras? Considering present seems to be dwapara Yuga, and ravana got his boon in treta Yuga, arjuna got pashupatastra from shiva and various astra from indra in dwapara? and not kaliyuga? Or is it kaliyuga so gods can't appear?

Comment: In Turiya you go beyond gods. So whichever God you call will come.

Comment: What about boons, astras? Would I be granted with?

Comment: What about Parashurama, who's going to be a saptarishi of next yuga along with Ashwattama, he's said to be waiting for Kalki's arrival, to bestow him with divine astras, teach mantras at mahendragiri, just like how he gave sudrashana chakra, other astravidya to krishna, can he appear to, if a pure turiya saraswat Brahmin who seeks him there? To teach him astra vidya?

Comment: But do they appear with their original form or can they take any form, like how shiva appeared as kirata first to test arjuna

Comment: Also is there any ahavana mantras to invite, invoke astra devatas into body of a turiya Brahmin?

Comment: @Aoi.T_015: Similar question was asked by you - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35114/3869 - Is this question necessary?

Comment: Will u require a boon in Turiya? Think.

Comment: Testing will be done before you reach Turiya!

Comment: What is "a turiya person"? @Aoi.T_015